# Learning latex; not satisfied with my tables

Tags: tables

The past few weeks I have put a huge effort into learning LateX for writing my thesis. However, making nice tables reamains a difficult job for me. I have provided a MWE of the 3 main tables I use below. I am wondering if some of you have some tips to make my tables look better. Besides those tips for the general improvement of my tables i'm wondering how:

- The number of observations (last row of tables 1 and 3) can be in line with the numbers in the other rows?
- The text under a table can be in line with the width of the table? As I assume this is a convention in making tables?
- If there is another possibility to show my readers that the rows can be viewed as groups, without using horizontal lines?  See the tables on page 2 and 4. Some dates belong to particular groups in table 1 and I want to make this clear to my reader. In table 3 I want to group certain variables, therefore I use the horizontal lines.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Yannick

**EDIT:** the first MWE generated an error, due to the second table. I have deleted that table in the MWE below:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
textwidth=155mm,
top=23.5mm,
bottom=23.5mm,
footskip=40pt,
heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Estimation Results Equation 11}
\sisetup{
output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
exponent-product={},
retain-explicit-plus,
input-open-uncertainty  = ,
input-close-uncertainty = ,
table-align-text-pre    = false,
table-align-text-post = false,
round-mode=places,
round-precision=3,
table-space-text-pre    = (,
table-space-text-post   = ),
}
\resizebox*{!}{\textheight}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}]}
\toprule\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{US TP} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{US OIS} \\ \midrule
Constant                     & 0.059                     & -0.095                     \\
$\Delta y_{t-1}$             & -0.267***                 &  \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 1}}                           \\
25-11-2008                   & 4.142                     & -29.389***                 \\
25-11-2008 ($t+1$)           & -1.899                    & -6.033                     \\
01-12-2008                   & 0.284                     & -19.282***                 \\
01-12-2008 ($t+1$)           & 5.071*                    & -5.366                     \\
16-12-2008                   & 0.894                     & -30.548***                 \\
16-12-2008 ($t+1$)           & -12.920***                & 0.733                      \\
28-01-2009                   & -7.161***                 & 13.256**                   \\
28-01-2009 ($t+1$)           & -3.065                    & 20.982***                  \\
18-03-2009                   & -17.389***                & -38.322***                 \\
18-03-2009 ($t+1$)           & -11.911***                & 7.639                      \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 2}}                           \\
10-08-2010                   & -1.085                    & -4.305                     \\
10-08-2010 ($t+1$)           & -2.208                    & -4.024                     \\
27-08-2010                   & -0.260                    & 17.874***                  \\
27-08-2010 ($t+1$)           & -0.470                    & -12.380**                  \\
21-09-2010                   & -1.229                    & -12.582**                  \\
21-09-2010 ($t+1$)           & -3.621                    & 0.248                      \\
15-10-2010                   & 3.193                     & 4.264                      \\
15-10-2010 ($t+1$)           & 1.456                     & -5.798                     \\
03-11-2010                   & -0.211                    & -2.045                     \\
03-11-2010 ($t+1$)           & -7.182***                 & -3.722                     \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{FG \& OT}}                         \\
09-08-2011                   & 8.191***                  & -8.668                     \\
09-08-2011 ($t+1$)           & 2.114                     & -14.568**                  \\
21-09-2011                   & -0.099                    & -7.089                     \\
21-09-11 ($t+1$)             & -12.643***                & -4.917                     \\
25-01-2012                   & -2.363                    & -5.459                     \\
25-01-2012 ($t+1$)           & -1.170                    & -5.140                     \\
20-06-2012                   & -2.264                    & 3.829                      \\
20-06-2012 ($t+1$)           & -2.247                    & -2.510                     \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 3}}                           \\
22-08-2012                   & 0.217                     & -10.419*                   \\
22-08-2012 ($t+1$)           & -4.278***                 & -0.952                     \\
31-08-2012                   & 2.075                     & -7.103                     \\
31-08-2012 ($t+1$)           & -0.130                    & 0.816                      \\
13-09-2012                   & 7.971***                  & -5.310                     \\
13-09-2012 ($t+1$)           & -0.834                    & 12.160**                   \\
12-12-2012                   & 0.063                     & 4.113                      \\
12-12-2012 ($t+1$)           & 0.035                     & 2.671                      \\
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tapering}}                         \\
22-05-2013                   & -2.957                    & 11.709*                    \\
22-05-2013 ($t+1$)           & 1.230                     & -1.666                     \\
19-06-2013                   & -7.186***                 & 18.181***                  \\
19-06-2013 ($t+1$)           & 8.391***                  & 6.099                      \\
18-12-2013                   & -3.518                    & 6.574                      \\
18-12-2013 ($t+1$)           & 0.310                     & 5.909                      \\ \midrule
$\Delta CESI_{vs}$           & -0.017*                   & 0.163***                   \\
$\Delta CESI_{EU}$           &                           &  \\ \midrule
Observations                 & 1973                      & 1994                       \\
R-squared (adj.)             & 0.135                     & 0.096                      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption*{\textbf{Notes:} Dependent variables in first differences. For the US, the date dummies are equal to one on the specified date ($t$), while for the EU the date dummies equal one the day after the specified date. *,**,*** denote the 10 percent, 5 percent and 1 percent significance levels, respectively.}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}}
\end{table}
\begin{sidewaystable}[h!]
\caption{Estimation Results Equation 12}
\sisetup{
output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
exponent-product={},
retain-explicit-plus,
input-open-uncertainty  = ,
input-close-uncertainty = ,
table-align-text-pre    = false,
table-align-text-post = false,
round-mode=places,
round-precision=3,
table-space-text-pre    = (,
table-space-text-post   = ),
}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}]S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}] S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}]}
\toprule\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Austria} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Belgium} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Finland} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{France} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Germany} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Netherlands} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Greece} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Italy} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Ireland} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Portugal} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Spain} \\ \midrule
Constant                  & -0.067    & -0.010     & -0.044    & -0.073     & 0.013     & -0.018      & 0.136     & -0.017     & -0.145    & 0.053      & 0.003      \\
QE 1                      & -1.849*** & -1.059     & -0.936*** & -3.690***  & -5.896*** & -4.783***   & 0.639     & 2.053      & 6.530***  & 0.442      & 0.658**    \\
QE 1 (2nd day)            & -3.500    & -4.230**   & -5.814*** & -5.979***  & -6.244*** & -5.755***   & -10.341** & -3.975***  & 1.967     & -5.376***  & -2.319**   \\
QE 2                      & 0.342     & -3.905***  & -0.504*   & 0.991***   & -1.894*** & -0.658      & 30.766*** & 5.638***   & 37.893    & 15.763***  & 6.831***   \\
QE 2 (2nd day)            & 0.522*    & -3.449***  & -0.855    & 0.594***   & 0.096     & -1.065***   & 11.103*** & -5.017***  & 31.425    & -10.836*** & -6.417***  \\
QE 3                      & -1.864*** & 3.147      & -0.864*** & -0.541*    & -3.056*** & -0.774***   & -3.950    & 1.622***   & -2.682*** & 18.524***  & 5.431***   \\
QE 3 (2nd day)            & -1.894*** & -7.920***  & -1.971*** & -1.683***  & -1.470*** & -1.841***   & 26.800*** & -15.558*** & 2.693***  & 0.911      & -12.520*** \\
FG                        & -0.410    & 0.341      & 2.411***  & 4.263***   & 3.445***  & 1.053***    & 8.496***  & -11.766*** & -5.652*** & 1.900      & -10.116*** \\
FG (2nd day)              & -8.580*** & -11.539*** & 0.761***  & -11.181*** & 4.038***  & 0.399**     & 16.614*** & -9.676***  & -3.559**  & -24.045*** & -3.557***  \\
OT                        & -1.133**  & -2.001     & -1.381*** & -6.644***  & -0.789**  & -0.266      & -35.205** & -12.462*** & 10.440*** & -15.524*** & -19.544*** \\
OT (2nd day)              & -2.227    & -6.233***  & -1.103*** & 1.309***   & -0.874    & -1.443***   & 20.981    & 13.201***  & 8.346***  & 14.632***  & 4.904      \\
Taper                     & 4.832     & -1.255     & -2.462    & 2.029***   & 0.217     & 3.740***    & 45.099*** & 3.081***   & 11.397*** & -3.917     & 5.224***   \\
Taper (2nd day)           & 11.356    & -2.973     & -11.508   & -0.734     & 1.527***  & -1.603      & 62.386*** & 4.573***   & -7.958*** & -16.712    & 3.125***   \\ \midrule
VSTOXX                    & 0.096     & 3.966***   & -1.849*   & 1.574*     & -6.704*** & -1.683***   & 20.598*** & 14.519***  & 14.253*** & 21.830***  & 15.737***  \\
CDS10y                    & 0.226***  & 0.253***   & -0.085    & 0.163***   & -0.129*** & 0.076***    & 0.035**   & 0.526**    & 0.349***  & 0.548***   & 0.540***   \\
Quanto CDS                & -0.010    & 0.281***   & 0.029     & 0.125***   &           & 0.035       & -0.028    & 0.103**    & 0.092*    & 0.212***   & 0.246***   \\
Bid ask spread            & 0.072     & 0.216      & 0.004***  & 0.055*     & 1.062**   & -0.213      & 0.169     & 0.001      & 0.039     & 0.057      & 0.144      \\
CESI                      & -0.001    & -0.000     & -0.001    & -0.001     & -0.001**  & -0.000      & -0.003    & -0.000     & 0.001     & -0.001     & -0.000     \\
ECB ann.                  & -0.786    & -1.767**   & -1.430**  & -1.597***  & -0.788*   & -1.453*     & -2.866**  & -1.484*    & -1.805**  & -1.782*    & -2.131*    \\ \midrule
$\Delta y_{t-1}$          & -0.141**  & 0.049      & -0.195*** & -0.142*    & -0.185**  & -0.149***   & 0.079*    & -0.061*    & 0.056*    & 0.079*     & -0.049     \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,Italy}$    & 0.014     & 0.073*     & 0.021     & 0.014      & -0.056**  & -0.008      & 0.255**   &            & 0.105*    & 0.059      & 0.025      \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,Spain}$    & -0.031    & -0.037*    & -0.034    & -0.011     & 0.013     & -0.017      & -0.205    & -0.008     & -0.049    & -0.139*    &            \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,Portugal}$ & -0.010    & -0.012     & -0.001    & -0.011     & 0.002     & 0.001       & 0.111     & -0.011     & -0.004    &            & -0.029*    \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,Ireland}$  & 0.033     & 0.024*     & 0.022*    & 0.035*     & 0.016     & 0.001       & -0.020    & 0.027      &           & 0.005      & 0.032      \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,Greece}$   & -0.000    & -0.001     & -0.000    & -0.002     & 0.001     & -0.000      &           & -0.006*    & -0.004    & -0.006     & -0.005**   \\
ARCH                      &           &            &           &            &           &             &           &            &           &            &            \\ \midrule
Constant                  & 0.177**   & 0.540***   & 0.193**   & 0.328***   & 0.174***  & 0.183***    & 7.338***  & 0.516***   & 1.309***  & 0.366***   & 0.440**    \\
L.arch                    & 0.128***  & 0.075***   & 0.151***  & 0.055***   & 0.158***  & 0.167***    & 0.160**   & 0.057***   & 0.207***  & 0.218***   & 0.060***   \\
L(2).arch                 & -0.092**  &            & -0.117*** &            & -0.129*** & -0.133***   & 0.573*    &            & 0.279*    & -0.159***  &            \\
L.garch                   & 0.958***  & 0.909***   & 0.960***  & 0.936***   & 0.965***  & 0.959***    & 0.613***  & 0.932***   & 0.517***  & 0.942***   & 0.933***   \\ \midrule
Observations              & 2111      & 2190       & 2128      & 2039       & 2190      & 2111        & 2190      & 2190       & 1982      & 1965       & 2039       \\
AIC                       & 6.072635  & 6.174726   & 6.101     & 6.163      & 6.108     & 6.013       & 9.013     & 6.478      & 6.757     & 7.360      & 6.620      \\
BIC                       & 6.150320  & 6.247496   & 6.178     & 6.240      & 6.181     & 6.091       & 9.086     & 6.549      & 6.836     & 7.439      & 6.695     \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\bigskip
\footnotesize{\textbf{Notes:} The table present the estimation results of equation 12. The dependent variables are in first differences and the results are showed in basis points. Bollerslev-Woolridge standard errors have been used to compute the coefficient covariance matrix. *,**,*** denote the 10 percent, 5 percent and 1 percent significance levels, respectively.}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Here in a separate MWE the table which gives the error: **Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used. \end{tabular}}**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
textwidth=155mm,
top=23.5mm,
bottom=23.5mm,
footskip=40pt,
heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Expected effect of the QE programs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm} llll}
\toprule \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{QE 1}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{QE 2}           & \multicolumn{1}{l}{QE 3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FG} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{OT} & \multicolumn{1}{}{Taper} &  \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Term premium}}                                                                                                                                                                                                               &  \\
Incorporated ann.                                         & 16-12-2008 , 18-03-2009                        & 03-11-2010                         & 22-08-2012               & 09-08-2012             & 21-09-2011             & 19-06-2013               &  \\
Expected effect                                           & $-$                                            & $-$                                & $-$                      & $-$                    & $-$                    & $+$                      &  \\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Yield}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & \\
Incorporated ann.                                         & 25-01-2008, 01-12-2008, 16-12-2008, 18-03-2009 & 27-08-2010, 21-09-2010, 03-11-2010 & 22-08-2012, 13-09-2012   & 09-08-2012             & 21-06-2011             & 22-05-2013, 19-06-2013   &  \\
Expected effect                                           & $--$                                           & $--$                               & $--$                     & $--$                   & $--$                   & $++$                     &  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}}
\tiny{\textbf{Notes:} A  $-$ indicates a negative effect, while a  $+$ indicates a positive effect. $--<-$ and $++>+$.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot compile your **not** MWE on my system (**! Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used.**). Can you?

Comment: I get the same error, but I can view the file using TexStudio. What can I do about the error?

Comment: Yannick, could you try to reduce your example to a **minimum** working example? Add a pdf to illustrate the problem?  (I agree that setting tables in tex is not so funny - however sometimes it seems harder than it is if you try to be a bit flexible about the design and consider to tackle your table from a different perspective .... i.e. direct "translating" from excel style data is possibly not a good idea. I cannot tell if this could be your problem due to lacking table view :-/ )

Comment: @Eva, I will try to minimize my working example, although I already deleted a lot of packages. Or do you mean that I only have to include one table per MWE? I will also upload a pdf in a minute.

Comment: @Eva , I have split the MWE's, see the EDIT. I hope my post is well readable now.

Answer (score 5):

Your empty preamble is simply as the error message says a missing preamble (in a `\multicolumn` The error was not reported until the `}}` at the end of the table as you have the resizebox which forces the whole table to be scanned before processing starts.

If you can't spot such an error a useful technique is to comment out the resizebox (which typographically is always a disaster applied to tables anyway) but just for debugging so errors can be reported as the table is processed. You would then get the error

```
! Package array Error: Empty preamble: `l' used.

See the array package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.25 ...olumn{1}{l}{OT} & \multicolumn{1}{}{Taper}
                                                   &  \\ \midrule
?
```

showing clearly the error is

```
\multicolumn{1}{}{Taper}
```

which is missing the alignment it should be

```
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Taper}
```

or

```
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Taper}
```

or whatever you need

Also note that size change commands do not take an argument the syntax should be not

```
\tiny{\textbf{Notes:} A  $-$ ...
```

but

```
\tiny\textbf{Notes:} A  $-$ ...
```

with the scope of the size change ending at `\end{table}`

having removed the `\resizebox` to demonstrate debugging technique, it seems a shame to put it back (scaling tables in that way produces inconsistent sizing and should only ever be a really last resort) So here is the table, at `\footnotesize` with no further scaling applied.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
textwidth=155mm,
top=23.5mm,
bottom=23.5mm,
footskip=40pt,
heightrounded,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Expected effect of the QE programs}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
%\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{
\footnotesize
\centering
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{tabular}{l*{6}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.8cm}}}
\toprule \toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{QE 1}                       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{QE 2}           & \multicolumn{1}{l}{QE 3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{FG} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{OT} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Taper}   \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Term premium}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\
Incorporated ann.                                         & 16-12-2008 , 18-03-2009                        & 03-11-2010                         & 22-08-2012               & 09-08-2012             & 21-09-2011             & 19-06-2013                \\
Expected effect                                           & $-$                                            & $-$                                & $-$                      & $-$                    & $-$                    & $+$                       \\
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{Yield}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\
Incorporated ann.                                         & 25-01-2008, 01-12-2008, 16-12-2008, 18-03-2009 & 27-08-2010, 21-09-2010, 03-11-2010 & 22-08-2012, 13-09-2012   & 09-08-2012             & 21-06-2011             & 22-05-2013, 19-06-2013    \\
Expected effect                                           & $--$                                           & $--$                               & $--$                     & $--$                   & $--$                   & $++$                      \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip

\textbf{Notes:} A  $-$ indicates a negative effect, while a  $+$ indicates a positive effect. $--<-$ and $++>+$.
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Creating informative and visually appealing tables is a challenge, no doubt. You've come quite a ways already, though! Some comments:

- Don't overuse **bold face**. With bold face, it's depressingly easy to come across as SHOUTING. Trust me: Very few readers like to be yelled at.
- Unless the end of the world is near, don't use `\resizebox` to shoehorn the tables into the text block. Aside: What if the end of the world really is near? Easy: Don't finish the table -- nobody is going to care...
- I suggest you use `longtable` for the first table, `tabularx` for the second, and `tabular*` for the third. The second and third tables should be set in landscape mode; I suggest you use `sidewaystable` environments for them.
- The first and second tables can be typeset in the regular font size (11pt, right?). The third requires the use of `\small`. The third table will still be a bit too tall for the page block, but it won't be obvious. If you really care about this issue, change `\small` to `\footnotesize`. In the code below, I applied very abbreviations to some of the material in the first column of Table 3.
- You get brownie points for using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package. But: Don't ever use consecutive `\toprule` directives -- unless you want to make the table look vulgar. Do look into using that package's `\addlinespace` macro, though -- whitespace can be a very effective visual divider.
- Be careful with the argument of the `table-format` option: Don't specify too many digits.
- Variable names should not be typeset in TeX's math mode. Use either math-roman or math-italic. In the code below, I use `\mathrm`.
- If you want to apply simple centering to material in an `S` column, encase the material in curly braces.

The following screenshot shows only the third table. I trust you can figure out how to compile and display tables 1 and 2 on your own. :-)

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[textwidth=155mm,top=23.5mm,bottom=23.5mm,
     footskip=40pt,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[skip=0.33\baselineskip]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\vn[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty  = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-align-text-pre    = false,
         table-align-text-post   = false,
        }
\begin{longtable}{@{}l
    *{2}{S[table-format=-2.3, table-space-text-post = {***}]}@{}}

\caption{Estimation Results Equation 11}\label{tab:results11}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Variable} & {US TP} & {US OIS} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{Table \ref{tab:results11}, cont'd}\\
\addlinespace
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Variable} & {US TP} & {US OIS} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{r@{}}{(cont'd on following page)}\\
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
Constant            & 0.059            & -0.095        \\
$\Delta y_{t-1}$    & -0.267***        &  \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 1}} \\
25-11-2008          & 4.142            & -29.389***    \\
25-11-2008 ($t{+}1$)  & -1.899           & -6.033        \\
01-12-2008          & 0.284            & -19.282***    \\
01-12-2008 ($t{+}1$)  & 5.071*           & -5.366        \\
16-12-2008          & 0.894            & -30.548***    \\
16-12-2008 ($t{+}1$)  & -12.920***       & 0.733         \\
28-01-2009          & -7.161***        & 13.256**      \\
28-01-2009 ($t{+}1$)  & -3.065           & 20.982***     \\
18-03-2009          & -17.389***       & -38.322***    \\
18-03-2009 ($t{+}1$)  & -11.911***       & 7.639         \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 2}} \\
10-08-2010          & -1.085           & -4.305        \\
10-08-2010 ($t{+}1$)  & -2.208           & -4.024        \\
27-08-2010          & -0.260           & 17.874***     \\
27-08-2010 ($t{+}1$)  & -0.470           & -12.380**     \\
21-09-2010          & -1.229           & -12.582**     \\
21-09-2010 ($t{+}1$)  & -3.621           & 0.248         \\
15-10-2010          & 3.193            & 4.264         \\
15-10-2010 ($t{+}1$)  & 1.456            & -5.798        \\
03-11-2010          & -0.211           & -2.045        \\
03-11-2010 ($t{+}1$)  & -7.182***        & -3.722        \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{FG \& OT}} \\
09-08-2011          & 8.191***         & -8.668        \\
09-08-2011 ($t{+}1$)  & 2.114            & -14.568**     \\
21-09-2011          & -0.099           & -7.089        \\
21-09-11 ($t{+}1$)    & -12.643***       & -4.917        \\
25-01-2012          & -2.363           & -5.459        \\
25-01-2012 ($t{+}1$)  & -1.170           & -5.140        \\
20-06-2012          & -2.264           & 3.829         \\
20-06-2012 ($t{+}1$)  & -2.247           & -2.510        \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 3}} \\
22-08-2012          & 0.217            & -10.419*      \\
22-08-2012 ($t{+}1$)  & -4.278***        & -0.952        \\
31-08-2012          & 2.075            & -7.103        \\
31-08-2012 ($t{+}1$)  & -0.130           & 0.816         \\
13-09-2012          & 7.971***         & -5.310        \\
13-09-2012 ($t{+}1$)  & -0.834           & 12.160**      \\
12-12-2012          & 0.063            & 4.113         \\
12-12-2012 ($t{+}1$)  & 0.035            & 2.671         \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tapering}} \\
22-05-2013          & -2.957           & 11.709*       \\
22-05-2013 ($t{+}1$)  & 1.230            & -1.666        \\
19-06-2013          & -7.186***        & 18.181***     \\
19-06-2013 ($t{+}1$)  & 8.391***         & 6.099         \\
18-12-2013          & -3.518           & 6.574         \\
18-12-2013 ($t{+}1$)  & 0.310            & 5.909         \\ 
\midrule
$\Delta \vn{CESI}_{\vn{US}}$  & -0.017* & 0.163***      \\
$\Delta \vn{CESI}_{\vn{EU}}$  &         &  \\ 
\midrule
Observations        & {1973}           & {1994}        \\
R-squared (adj.)    & 0.135            & 0.096         \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}
\noindent
Notes: Dependent variables in first differences. For the US, the date dummies are equal to 1 on the specified date ($t$), while for the EU the date dummies equal 1 the day after the specified date. *,**,*** denote the 10 percent, 5 percent and 1 percent significance levels, respectively.
\endgroup

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Expected effect of the QE programs}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l *{6}{L} @{}}
\toprule 
& QE 1 & QE 2 & QE 3 & FG & OT & Taper \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\textbf{Term premium}} \\
Incorporated ann. & 16-12-2008 , 18-03-2009 & 03-11-2010                & 22-08-2012 & 09-08-2012 & 21-09-2011 & 19-06-2013 \\
Expected effect & $-$ & $-$ & $-$& $-$ & $-$ & $+$ \\
\addlinespace
\multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{\textbf{Yield}} \\
Incorporated ann.  & 25-01-2008, 01-12-2008, 16-12-2008, 18-03-2009 & 27-08-2010, 21-09-2010, 03-11-2010 & 22-08-2012, 13-09-2012  & 09-08-2012 & 21-06-2011 & 22-05-2013, 19-06-2013 \\
Expected effect  & $--$ & $--$ & $--$ & $--$ & $--$          & $++$\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\medskip
Notes: A $-$ indicates a negative effect, while a $+$ indicates a positive effect. ${--}<{-}$ and ${++}>{+}$.
\end{sidewaystable}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\caption{Estimation Results Equation 12}
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty  = ,
         input-close-uncertainty = ,
         table-align-text-pre    = false,
         table-align-text-post = false,
         round-mode=places,
         round-precision=3,
        }
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\small
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                *{12}{S[table-format=-2.3, 
                        table-space-text-post = {***}]} }
\toprule
Variable & {Austria} & {Belgium} & {Finland} & {France} & {Germany} & {Netherl.} & {Greece} & {Italy} & {Ireland} & {Portugal} & {Spain} \\ 
\midrule
Constant         & -0.067    & -0.010     & -0.044    & -0.073     & 0.013     & -0.018      & 0.136     & -0.017     & -0.145    & 0.053      & 0.003      \\
QE 1             & -1.849*** & -1.059     & -0.936*** & -3.690***  & -5.896*** & -4.783***   & 0.639     & 2.053      & 6.530***  & 0.442      & 0.658**    \\
QE 1 ($t{+}1$)   & -3.500    & -4.230**   & -5.814*** & -5.979***  & -6.244*** & -5.755***   & -10.341** & -3.975***  & 1.967     & -5.376***  & -2.319**   \\
QE 2             & 0.342     & -3.905***  & -0.504*   & 0.991***   & -1.894*** & -0.658      & 30.766*** & 5.638***   & 37.893    & 15.763***  & 6.831***   \\
QE 2 ($t{+}1$)   & 0.522*    & -3.449***  & -0.855    & 0.594***   & 0.096     & -1.065***   & 11.103*** & -5.017***  & 31.425    & -10.836*** & -6.417***  \\
QE 3             & -1.864*** & 3.147      & -0.864*** & -0.541*    & -3.056*** & -0.774***   & -3.950    & 1.622***   & -2.682*** & 18.524***  & 5.431***   \\
QE 3 ($t{+}1$)   & -1.894*** & -7.920***  & -1.971*** & -1.683***  & -1.470*** & -1.841***   & 26.800*** & -15.558*** & 2.693***  & 0.911      & -12.520*** \\
FG               & -0.410    & 0.341      & 2.411***  & 4.263***   & 3.445***  & 1.053***    & 8.496***  & -11.766*** & -5.652*** & 1.900      & -10.116*** \\
FG ($t{+}1$)     & -8.580*** & -11.539*** & 0.761***  & -11.181*** & 4.038***  & 0.399**     & 16.614*** & -9.676***  & -3.559**  & -24.045*** & -3.557***  \\
OT               & -1.133**  & -2.001     & -1.381*** & -6.644***  & -0.789**  & -0.266      & -35.205** & -12.462*** & 10.440*** & -15.524*** & -19.544*** \\
OT ($t{+}1$)     & -2.227    & -6.233***  & -1.103*** & 1.309***   & -0.874    & -1.443***   & 20.981    & 13.201***  & 8.346***  & 14.632***  & 4.904      \\
Taper            & 4.832     & -1.255     & -2.462    & 2.029***   & 0.217     & 3.740***    & 45.099*** & 3.081***   & 11.397*** & -3.917     & 5.224***   \\
Taper ($t{+}1$)  & 11.356    & -2.973     & -11.508   & -0.734     & 1.527***  & -1.603      & 62.386*** & 4.573***   & -7.958*** & -16.712    & 3.125***   \\ 
\midrule
VSTOXX           & 0.096     & 3.966***   & -1.849*   & 1.574*     & -6.704*** & -1.683***   & 20.598*** & 14.519***  & 14.253*** & 21.830***  & 15.737***  \\
CDS10y           & 0.226***  & 0.253***   & -0.085    & 0.163***   & -0.129*** & 0.076***    & 0.035**   & 0.526**    & 0.349***  & 0.548***   & 0.540***   \\
Quanto CDS       & -0.010    & 0.281***   & 0.029     & 0.125***   &  & 0.035       & -0.028    & 0.103**    & 0.092*    & 0.212***   & 0.246***   \\
Bid-ask spr.   & 0.072     & 0.216      & 0.004***  & 0.055*     & 1.062**   & -0.213      & 0.169     & 0.001      & 0.039     & 0.057      & 0.144      \\
CESI             & -0.001    & -0.000     & -0.001    & -0.001     & -0.001**  & -0.000      & -0.003    & -0.000     & 0.001     & -0.001     & -0.000     \\
ECB ann.         & -0.786    & -1.767**   & -1.430**  & -1.597***  & -0.788*   & -1.453*     & -2.866**  & -1.484*    & -1.805**  & -1.782*    & -2.131*    \\ 
\midrule
$\Delta y_{t-1}$ & -0.141**  & 0.049      & -0.195*** & -0.142*    & -0.185**  & -0.149***   & 0.079*    & -0.061*    & 0.056*    & 0.079*     & -0.049     \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,\vn{Italy}}$    & 0.014     & 0.073*     & 0.021     & 0.014      & -0.056**  & -0.008      & 0.255**   &   & 0.105*    & 0.059      & 0.025      \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,\vn{Spain}}$    & -0.031    & -0.037*    & -0.034    & -0.011     & 0.013     & -0.017      & -0.205    & -0.008     & -0.049    & -0.139*    &            \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,\vn{Portugal}}$ & -0.010    & -0.012     & -0.001    & -0.011     & 0.002     & 0.001       & 0.111     & -0.011     & -0.004    &   & -0.029*    \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,\vn{Ireland}} $  & 0.033     & 0.024*     & 0.022*    & 0.035*     & 0.016     & 0.001       & -0.020    & 0.027      &  & 0.005      & 0.032      \\
$\Delta y_{t-1,\vn{Greece}}$   & -0.000    & -0.001     & -0.000    & -0.002     & 0.001     & -0.000      &  & -0.006*    & -0.004    & -0.006     & -0.005**   \\
ARCH  \\ 
\midrule
Constant         & 0.177**   & 0.540***   & 0.193**   & 0.328***   & 0.174***  & 0.183***    & 7.338***  & 0.516***   & 1.309***  & 0.366***   & 0.440**    \\
L.arch           & 0.128***  & 0.075***   & 0.151***  & 0.055***   & 0.158***  & 0.167***    & 0.160**   & 0.057***   & 0.207***  & 0.218***   & 0.060***   \\
L(2).arch        & -0.092**  &   & -0.117*** &   & -0.129*** & -0.133***   & 0.573*    &   & 0.279*    & -0.159***  &            \\
L.garch          & 0.958***  & 0.909***   & 0.960***  & 0.936***   & 0.965***  & 0.959***    & 0.613***  & 0.932***   & 0.517***  & 0.942***   & 0.933***   \\ 
\midrule
Obs. & {2111} & {2190} & {2128} & {2039} & {2190} & {2111} & {2190} & {2190} & {1982} & {1965} & {2039}\\
AIC              & 6.072635  & 6.174726   & 6.101     & 6.163      & 6.108     & 6.013       & 9.013     & 6.478      & 6.757     & 7.360      & 6.620      \\
BIC              & 6.150320  & 6.247496   & 6.178     & 6.240      & 6.181     & 6.091       & 9.086     & 6.549      & 6.836     & 7.439      & 6.695     \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\medskip
Notes: The table present the estimation results of equation 12. The dependent variables are in first differences and the results are showed in basis points. Bollerslev-Woolridge standard errors have been used to compute the coefficient covariance matrix. *,**,*** denote the 10 percent, 5 percent and 1 percent significance levels, respectively.
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! As I have a strict page limit, I have to use the resizebox command. Table 1 has to fit on one page. And table 2 needs to fit horizontally on one page, as I have text below this table. Your version of table 3 looks much better :)

Comment: @peter - Do consider deleting all non-essential stuff from tables 1 and 2. :-)

Comment: how can I round the numbers in my table to 2 digtis after the   point? If I change S[table-format=-2.3,table-space-text-post = {***}]} into S[table-format=-2.2, table-space-text-post = {***}]}, the numbers have still 3 digits after the point.

Comment: @peter - To change the rounding behavior,you must also change `round-precision=3` to `round-precision=2`.

Comment: thank you. Last question regarding your initial comment: you  use ''\mathrm''. Does this package fits the overall style of my document? I use the lmodern font. Furthermore, it seems that your version of table 3 looks different than the other tables ( in terms of font).

Comment: @peter - The font family is the same in all three tables; the first two (implicitly) use `\normalsize`, whereas the third uses `\small`. `\small` is about 10% smaller than `\normalsize`. I'm afraid I don't know much at all about the "overall style of your document". (How could I?) You'll need to decide whether `\mathrm` or `\mathit` is more to your liking. For sure, don't use direct math mode.

Answer (score 3):

Table 1 can perfectly fit on one page, with a `\small` font size, redesigning the table layout, so it splits into two tables (the multiplication of the tables miracle ;o)):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
textwidth=155mm,
top=23.5mm,
bottom=23.5mm,
footskip=40pt,
heightrounded, showframe ]{geometry}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{rotfloat}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\caption{Estimation Results Equation 11}
\sisetup{
output-exponent-marker = \text{e},
exponent-product={},
retain-explicit-plus,
input-open-uncertainty = ,
input-close-uncertainty = ,
table-align-text-pre = false,
table-align-text-post = false,
round-mode=places,
round-precision=3,
table-space-text-pre = (,
table-space-text-post = ),
table-number-alignment=center}
\centering\small\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tl}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l*{2}{S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}]}@{}}
\toprule\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{US TP} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{US OIS} \\
 \midrule
Constant & 0.059 & -0.095 \\
$\Delta y_{t-1}$ & -0.267*** & \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 1}} \\
\midrule
25-11-2008 & 4.142 & -29.389*** \\
\makecell{25-11-2008\\ ($t+1$)} & -1.899 & -6.033 \\
\addlinespace
01-12-2008 & 0.284 & -19.282*** \\
\makecell{01-12-2008\\ ($t+1$)} & 5.071* & -5.366 \\
\addlinespace
16-12-2008 & 0.894 & -30.548*** \\
\makecell{16-12-2008\\ ($t+1$)} & -12.920*** & 0.733 \\
\addlinespace
28-01-2009 & -7.161*** & 13.256** \\
\makecell{28-01-2009\\ ($t+1$)} & -3.065 & 20.982*** \\
\addlinespace
18-03-2009 & -17.389*** & -38.322*** \\
\makecell{18-03-2009\\ ($t+1$)} & -11.911*** & 7.639 \\
 \midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 2}} \\
 \midrule
10-08-2010 & -1.085 & -4.305 \\
\makecell{10-08-2010\\ ($t+1$)} & -2.208 & -4.024 \\
\addlinespace
27-08-2010 & -0.260 & 17.874*** \\
\makecell{27-08-2010\\ ($t+1$)} & -0.470 & -12.380** \\
\addlinespace
21-09-2010 & -1.229 & -12.582** \\
\makecell{21-09-2010\\ ($t+1$)} & -3.621 & 0.248 \\
\addlinespace
15-10-2010 & 3.193 & 4.264 \\
\makecell{15-10-2010\\ ($t+1$)} & 1.456 & -5.798 \\
\addlinespace
03-11-2010 & -0.211 & -2.045 \\
\makecell{03-11-2010\\($t+1$)} & -7.182*** & -3.722 \\
\addlinespace
 \midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{FG \& OT}} \\
 \midrule
09-08-2011 & 8.191*** & -8.668 \\
\makecell{09-08-2011\\ ($t+1$)} & 2.114 & -14.568** \\
\addlinespace
\end{tabular}
%%%%%%
\hfill\renewcommand{\cellalign}{tl}
\begin{tabular}[t]{l*{2}{S[table-format=2.6, table-space-text-post = {***}]}@{}}
\toprule\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Variable} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{US TP} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{US OIS} \\
 \midrule
20-06-2012 & -2.264 & 3.829 \\%
\makecell{20-06-2012\\ ($t+1$)} & -2.247 & -2.510 \\%
\addlinespace
 21-09-2011 & -0.099 & -7.089 \\%
\makecell{21-09-2011\\ ($t+1$)} & -12.643*** & -4.917 \\%
\addlinespace
 22-08-2012 & 0.217 & -10.419* \\%
\makecell{22-08-2012\\ ($t+1$)} & -4.278*** & -0.952 \\%
\addlinespace
 25-01-2012 & -2.363 & -5.459 \\%
\makecell{25-01-2012\\ ($t+1$)} & -1.170 & -5.140 \\%
 \midrule
 \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{QE 3}} \\
 \midrule
 31-08-2012 & 2.075 & -7.103 \\
\makecell{31-08-2012 \\($t+1$)} & -0.130 & 0.816 \\
\addlinespace
13-09-2012 & 7.971*** & -5.310 \\
\makecell{13-09-2012\\ ($t+1$)} & -0.834 & 12.160** \\
\addlinespace
12-12-2012 & 0.063 & 4.113 \\
\makecell{12-12-2012\\ ($t+1$)} & 0.035 & 2.671 \\
 \midrule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Tapering}} \\
 \midrule
22-05-2013 & -2.957 & 11.709* \\
\makecell{22-05-2013\\($t+1$)} & 1.230 & -1.666 \\
\addlinespace
19-06-2013 & -7.186*** & 18.181*** \\
\makecell{19-06-2013\\ ($t+1$)} & 8.391*** & 6.099 \\
\addlinespace
18-12-2013 & -3.518 & 6.574 \\
\makecell{18-12-2013 \\($t+1$)} & 0.310 & 5.909 \\%
 \midrule
 $ \Delta CESI_{vs}$ & -0.017* & 0.163*** \\
$\Delta CESI_{EU}$ & & \\ \midrule
Observations & {1973} & {1994} \\
\makecell{R-squared\\ (adj.)} & 0.135 & 0.096 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption*{\textbf{Notes:} Dependent variables in first differences. For the US, the date dummies are equal to one on the specified date ($t$), while for the EU the date dummies equal one the day after the specified date.\\ *, **, *** denote the 10 percent, 5 percent and 1 percent significance levels, respectively.}
%\end{center}
%\end{minipage}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]